# nth-child(-n) no funciona en hijos con dos clases

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy con un problema que no puedo resolver. Tengo un **DIV** que contiene el mismo elemento varias veces **article** y este elemento a su vez tiene 2 clases, una clase que comparten todos y otras para diferenciarlos entre sí.

Quiero seleccionar los dos primeros elementos de una de esas clases, ejemplo: **.product3:nth-child(-n+2)** pero no funciona, tampoco puedo seleccionar colocando solo un número ej **.product3:nth-child(3)**

```css
.content-product {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.wrap-article {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.product1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.product2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.product3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.product3:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-product">
  <article class="wrap-article product1"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product1"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product1"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product1"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product1"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product2"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product2"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product2"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product2"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product2"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product3"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product3"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product3"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product3"></article>
  <article class="wrap-article product3"></article>
</div>
```

Les dejo lo que hice en codepen: https://codepen.io/RodBrull/pen/zYYNgbE

Agradecería mucho si me pueden ayudar.

Saludos

Comment: Si agregas un div que separe los article funaciona

Comment: Lo intenté, pero no puedo hacer una grilla continua. Si dejo los elementos en 3 columnas y pongo un div para separar cada bloque, faltará un elemento en cada bloque

Comment: @RodBrull ¿el resultado esperado sería [algo como esto](https://jsfiddle.net/945rwzxd/)?

Answer (score 3):

Desgraciadamente, todavía no es posible usar la pseudo-clase `nth-child` teniendo en cuenta las clases de nuestros elementos por lo que no vas a poder realizar lo que pretendes únicamente con CSS, si no que deberás ayudarte de Javascript o JQuery.

Por suerte, parece que en CSS4 (y esperemos que así sea) se va a ampliar la funcionalidad de esta pseudo-clase y se va a poder tener en cuenta el selector que le indiquemos, según se indica en el [borrador de CSS4 de Agosto de 2019](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) y cuya sintaxis sería la siguiente:

```
:nth-child(An+B [of S]?) {
    /* declarations */
}
```

en donde S sería nuestro selector, el cual puede ser opcional.

Aplicado a tu caso concreto quedaría algo así:

```
:nth-child(-n+2 of article.product3) {
   background-color: pink;
}
```

**ACLARACIÓN:** Al ser un borrador no es seguro que esta funcionalidad esté disponible en CSS4 o que sufra alguna modificación. De hecho, hubo una pseudo-clase precursora para poder seleccionar elementos teniendo en cuenta un selector, `nth-match`, que finalmente se desestimó para ampliar la funcionalidad de `nth-child`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, leí sobre esa nueva funcionalidad, que la encuentro genial, pero son muy pocos o creo que solo Chrome es el que soporta lo nuevo. Entonces seguiré tu consejo y lo hare con JS. Saludos

Comment: @RodBrull Según [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child), únicamente está soportado en Safari. Espero que muy pronto se aplique al resto de navegadores, ya que sería una funcionalidad muy útil.

Comment: La solución fue la que me dieron más arriba, separé los productos bloques y como tiene la propiedad flex, el flujo continuaba donde terminaba el otro producto.

Comment: @RodBrull Me alegro de que hayas encontrado una solución a tu problema!! Pensaba que no podrías modificar la estructura de tu HTML por eso te indiqué que actualmente no era viable realizarlo de una manera trivial con la estructura que tenías. Por ejemplo, para el caso que indicas en el ejemplo hubiera bastado con apuntar a los dos elementos directamente con `nth-child` pero me parecía una solución demasiado fea como para dártela como solución. Algo [así](https://jsfiddle.net/j5aLg1f7/). Entre la opción fea y JS, yo prefiero hacerlo con JS la verdad.